# Server refused our key - Putty trying to connect to a new VPS server

Tags: ssh, putty, hetzner

I am using Putty to connect to my VPS servers.
I have created a new VPS server (Hetzner cloud) and have chosen the existing SSH key, as a security measure.
When trying to connect to a newly created server over SSH (for the first time), Putty prints out "Server refused our key".
I chose the same SSH key that I had created 4 years ago - the one I use all the time to connect to my existing VPS servers. I do not have an idea why is not allowing me to
connect to a new server with absolutely the same key and same settings that I use to connect to my existing VPS servers without any problem.

Does someone have an idea what could I be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem somehow was in Putty application itself - I've had a 0.73 version and after an update to 0.78 I finally managed to connect to my new VPS server.